# how to set items to the array of objects using session Storage

Tags: javascript, session-storage

I have below piece of code

```
this.state.templateData.childList[0].data[0].body.labelname = response
```

How can i set response to the lablename using session storage with  key "templateData"?

Answer (score 0):

**If you want to set templateData to storage:**

```
// Save data to sessionStorage
sessionStorage.setItem('key', 'value');

// Get saved data from sessionStorage
var data = sessionStorage.getItem('key');

// Remove saved data from sessionStorage
sessionStorage.removeItem('key');

// Remove all saved data from sessionStorage
sessionStorage.clear();
```

In your case you can set the value as:

```
sessionStorage.setItem({ 'templateData': JSON.stringify(response) })
```

**If you want to retrieve the labelname from storage and fill 'response':**

```
response = sessionStorage.getItem('templateData')
```

Comment: thanks for reply ....but i want to set the value of 'response' to  'labelName ' which is one of the key of 'templateData'.